# how to print a string, provided as an argument in C++

Tags: visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
double prompt(string input )
{
    double input;
    cin>>input;
    return input;
}
int main()
{
    double answer;
    double euro = prompt("Enter the value in Euros :  ");
    answer=euro/1.583;
    cout<<answer;
    system ("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

i want to print "Enter the value in Euros :  " but it won't. 
and i get an error - 'return' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'double'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double prompt(string input ) {
    double input;
    cin>>input;
    return input;
}
```

String is called input and double is called input.... there is something wrong here.

Surely this should be something like:

```
double prompt(string promptStr)
{
    double input;
    cout << promptStr;
    cin >> input;
    return input;
}
```

Comment: thanks but i got an error '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in your program. I take it you want the `prompt` method to print a string and return its input? In that case you should `cout << promptArgument;`. Currently you are reading the string parameter.

```
double prompt(string promptArgument)
{
    cout << promptArgument;

    double input;
    cin >> input;
    return input;
}
```